# send large data using webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I need to send large data using webservice. the size of data would be between 300 MB to 700 MB. The webservice generates data from SQL database and send to the client. it is in form of DataSet with around 20 to 25 tables.
I tried solution from artical, ["How to: Enable a Web Service to Send and Receive Large Amounts of Data"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx) and sample fo Microsoft WSE 3.0, but mostly it is giving me "System.OutOfMemoryException".

I think the problem is WebService buffers data in memory on server and it crosses limit.

i thought two alternate, 
    (1) send DataTable one by one, but some time one DataTable can have around 100MB to 150MB data 
    (2)Write file on server and transfer using HttpWebRequest(FTP possible, but FTP server is not accessible currently)

can any one suggest workaround for this problem using webservice?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried BufferResponse attribute of web service.

Comment: Here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vbtskusingwebmethodattributeanchorbufferresponse

Comment: yes, sample code of Microsoft WSE 3.0 has [WebMethod(BufferResponse = false)]. but it is still giving OutOfMemory Exception

Answer (score 0):

A dataset will load all the data in memory. It is not suited to transfer that huge amounts of data. DataSets carry a lot of extra information when they are serialized.

If you know the structure of the tables you will need to transfer, create a set of `Serializable` objects and sending an array of those would help reduce your data payload significantly.

If you must use a `DataSet` take a look into enabling BinaryRemoting.

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
myDataSet.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;
bf.Serialize(s, ResultDataSet);
```

After reducing your data payload by such means, it would be best to write the files to a publicly accessible location on your http server. Hosting it over http allows clients to download the file far more easily than ftp. You can control access to these http folders by means of proper permissions given to the users.

Comment: I want to convert it using DataReader, but i didn't found any way to pass data without buffering using webservice. yes, last way is creating file and use over Http.